# With the Weiler-Atherton clipping algorithm what do I do with collinear segments?

Tags: 2d, polygon, clipping

I'm trying to implement a `Weiler-Atherton` clipping algorithm. I've read around a lot, and looked at sample code, and I can't seem to find anyone who talks about collinear line segments and how to deal with them.

For example, the two rectangles
    `[[0, 0], [0, 1], [3, 1], [3, 0]]` and `[[1, 0], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 0]]`
 have two overlapping line segments --`[[3, 0], [0, 0]]` overlaps with `[[2, 0], [1, 0]]`.

Most code I've read will treat these as parallel line segments and leaves out the intersection completely. Is that the best thing to do?

Answer (score 1):

So, right now, I **think** the answer is "ignore them". The two vertices of the overlap will also be intersections of other (non-colinear) line segments, so you can just handle them when dealing with those intersections.